# How to make commands that can be used only once an hour etc using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to code a discord bot that has an economy system and I want some commands to only be triggered once every hour so somebody can not spam them.(When a person uses the command a timer starts for only them and anybody else can use the command if their own timer isn't still on)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use date.time and if date.time < 1 hour then do whatever

Comment: You can use `commands.cooldown()`. Check out the [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown) for more information. This will add a cooldown to a command. **Example:** `@commands.cooldown(1, 5, BucketType.user)` - 5 sec. cooldown for the user.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def command(ctx):
    await ctx.send("command output")
```

This should work just change the command after the cooldown @